# Overpass Turbo: query for administrative level results in empty dataset

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, overpass-turbo

If I look up a city on openstreetmap, I can see it has an administrative level of 10. For example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/162798

Subsequently, I run a query in Overpass Turbo to extract the aministrative boundary of this city:

```
[out:json][timeout:60];    
{{geocodeArea:'s-Hertogenbosch}}->.searchArea;
    relation["admin_level"="10"](area.searchArea);
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;

{{style: 
  area
  { color:gray; fill-color:DarkGray; }
}}
```

However, this does not work (returns an empty dataset). If I set the admin_level to 8, it returns a much bigger area compared to what openstreetmap shows. For other cities, the admin_level 10 does work, so why not for 's-Hertogenbosch? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the name and the admin_level then just query directly for this element:

```
[out:json][timeout:60];    
relation["name"="'s-Hertogenbosch"]["admin_level"="10"];
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Unfortunately I can't tell why your original query fails.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't try to query it directly. Thinking too difficult again. But still strange that the original query results in an empty dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pivot` instead of querying for a relation inside itself. This is also more generic: you only need to know that the geocodeArea is a relation, but don't know the admin_level. What ends up in ".searchArea" depends on the "Nominatim" lookup that overpass turbo runs before sending the query to Overpass API. Results may be a bit random at times.

```
[out:json];    
{{geocodeArea:'s-Hertogenbosch}}->.searchArea;
rel(pivot.searchArea);
out geom;

{{style: 
  area
  { color:gray; fill-color:DarkGray; }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A late response but for anyone coming from Google:

This is a pretty useful query, just has a simple error, removing the extra " `);` " fixed it

```
[out:json][timeout:60];    
{{geocodeArea:'s-Hertogenbosch}}->.searchArea;
    relation["admin_level"="10"](area.searchArea);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;

{{style: 
  area
  { color:gray; fill-color:DarkGray; }
}}
```